# Can't remove old kernel images to free disk space to solve "linux-image-... but it is not installed" / "failed to write (No space left on device)"

Tags: debian, kernel, apt, upgrade

When I run `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt-get autoremove`, it returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-amd64 : Depends: linux-image-5.10.0-16-amd64 (= 5.10.127-2) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then, when I run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`, it returns:

```
[...]
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-5.10.0-16-amd64_5.10.127-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-5.10.0-16-amd64 (5.10.127-2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.10.0-16-amd64_5.10.127-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-16-amd64' to '/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-16-amd64.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-5.10.0-16-amd64_5.10.127-2_amd64.deb
```

I had nearly the same error on a second Debian11/KDE computer with the same error message.

There I could solve it using [these two commands from here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/622166/233262) to free disk space on the boot partition. However, the command to remove unneeded kernel images doesn't work on this computer: when I run

```
dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e '[0-9]'
```

it shows a number of kernel image filenames but when I run the full command

```
dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e '[0-9]' | xargs sudo apt -y purge
```

it doesn't remove them. The same filenames still show when I run the former command and no disk space is freed so my problem remains. The output of the above is:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-headers-amd64 : Depends: linux-headers-5.10.0-14-amd64 (= 5.10.113-1) but it is not going to be installed
linux-image-amd64 : Depends: linux-image-5.10.0-16-amd64 (= 5.10.127-2) but it is not going to be installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

---

- First of all, all of this shouldn't be needed as upgrades should run smoothly and be so easy to do that basically most grandmas could do it. If there are issues with available disk space, **it should prompt the user** (in the console as well as in GUIs like Apper if that's used for upgrading) to do things like clearing old kernel images (maybe using the command above) or running `sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/*` or clearing `/tmp` or running `sudo apt-get autoremove/autoclean` or other things depending how much disk space is needed and where. It should calculate how much disk space is needed and check if sufficient is available. Alternatively, if insufficient space is available, it could run the upgrades one at a time and clean up after each, or notify the user about it and abort the upgrade until enough disk space is available to prevent any issues. This is probably a separate question/issue. It's very inconvenient, outdated, insecure and user-unfriendly.
- **How to remove those old kernel images** to free up the required disk space? If that wouldn't be the recommended route to solving this problem (again, it worked on another computer where I also had this problem), then please (also?) add how you'd solve it instead.

Comment: IIRC apt-get prints an estimate of the disk space consumed by the packages it has identified to be downloaded/installed.  It's an easy message to ignore, and I've filled up my disk a number of times by ignoring it.  There are MANY parts of Linux that will give only weak warning you may shoot yourself in the foot and then allow you to proceed.  Caveat Sysadmintor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can’t help you with your first bullet point. To resolve your second one, you’ll have to temporarily remove `linux-headers-amd64` and `linux-image-amd64`:

```sh
sudo apt remove linux-{headers,image}-amd64
```

Then explicitly remove any installed kernel package other than the package corresponding to the running kernel:

```sh
dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk "NR>5 && \!/^un/ && \!/$(uname -r | cut -d- -f-2)/ { print \$2 }" | xargs sudo apt -y purge
```

Finally, install the latest kernel:

```sh
sudo apt install linux-{headers,image}-amd64
```

If you install `unattended-upgrades`, it will take care of removing automatically-installed kernels for you when they are no longer needed.

Comment: Already had `unattended-upgrades` installed. Output of first command:
`cat: write error: No space left on device
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-13-amd64 with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
[...]
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`
This solved it anyway.

Comment: The three commands didn't work on another machine. You also have to remove the unneeded kernel images. Edited your answer ("Before doing this...") to add the two needed commands. This should be fixed by Debian so people can upgrade properly.

Comment: In a default setup, `unattended-upgrades` does remove older kernels (it keeps the running kernel and the second-last kernel). If you think something needs to be fixed in Debian, please file a bug report.

Comment: *Without* `unattended-upgrades`, things get more complicated since kernels are explicitly protected from auto-removal.

Comment: I have `unattended-upgrades` installed on both machines that this occurred on and at least on one I had to run the two commands to remove old kernels (on the other I just ran them but didn't try without that). I couldn't know that it's a bug as I didn't know the expected relevant behavior of it. Is there some config one can make that prevents unattended-upgrades from removing old kernels? Maybe I only have it installed but disabled (it does run sometimes though).

Comment: There is one feature of `unattended-upgrades` which may explain things here: it won’t remove kernels if they are marked as manually installed. This if you ever manually installed a kernel package (*e.g.* `apt install linux-image-5.10.0-17-amd64`), that kernel won’t be removed by `unattended-upgrades`.

In a default Debian setup, `linux-image-amd64` (or equivalent for other architectures) is installed and pulls in the right package. The kernel packages themselves are automatically installed as dependencies, so they are removed automatically when no longer needed.

Comment: I didn't manually install them. The bug report is here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1017617